# Why app links bring extra dialog on Huawei

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, applinks, huawei-developers

When I have implemented app links for Huawei devices without GMS, I noticed that every time I test app link, it brings dialog asking user permission to open the app, which is kind of weird, as it looks more to be a deep link, not an app link.

Why app links doesn't work as suppose on Huawei devices without GMS?

Answer (score 1):

I have asked this question to the Huawei support, and here is the answer:

> If you are using Chrome, the Open dialog box is not displayed and the
> app will be automatically started.
>
> All browsers in China have banned the action of pulling up other
> applications; The user must manually click Open to pull up the
> tripartite application. This is stipulated by Chinese law.

Answer (score 0):

Why app links bring extra dialog on Huawei?

This should not happen on Huawei phones. When I run the testing on app linking using a Huawei HMS phone with the default browser in the US, I don’t have this issue.

Comment: Does your Huawei device has GMS? or when was the release date of your device?

Comment: No, Hayk, my phone does not have GMS.

Comment: BTW, my phone is Mate30

Comment: Strange enough. Do they have different configuration for browsers for different countries? Or Huawei developer support was lying? )))

Comment: Hi Hayk, as said, I run the testing in the US. I don’t know what’s happening in other countries. But I think Huawei developer support is right.